# Separable differential equations $y'=\tan (x+y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an exercise of separable differential equations

$$y'= \tan (x + y)$$

Solution: $$\ln | 1 + \sin 2(x + y) | + 2y-2y = c$$

The problem is that I cannot reach the solution.

Comment: Solve the separable equation $$z'=1+\tan z$$ and use $$y=z-x$$

Comment: @Did How would you implement it ? I do not understand you

Comment: Hmm, what? Which step do you fail to understand? There are only two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will try as much not to spoil the fun of solving it.

$$\text{Let $x+y = u$} \\ \implies \dfrac{du}{dx}= 1 + \dfrac{dy}{dx}\\ \implies \dfrac{du}{dx}= 1 + \tan u $$

Then try to proceed.

It should be fairly easy if you manipulate properly.